# Spring Boot - Starter-Data-Elasticsearch starts two ES nodes instead of one

Tags: java, spring, maven, elasticsearch, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot 1.2.5 and Spring-Boot-Starter-Data-Elasticsearch. I have a custom elasticsearch class which represents a node and connects to a remote ES instance. Everything works fine but when I start the application, two ES nodes are started instead of a single one (Overkill and Serpentina in the following log example).

I tried using Spring-Data-Elasticsearch or simply remove ES from pom but it did not help. Starter-Data-Elasticsearch is needed to fulfill dependencies and as soon as it's added, it starts two nodes.

I also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25524444/how-to-make-elasticsearch-embedded-accessible-via-localhost9200) and tried to add `spring.data.elasticsearch.local=false` to application.properties but it didn't change anything.

I tried adding `@EnableConfigurationProperties(ElasticsearchProperties.class)` to my application class but the application doesn't start because of missing dependencies.

I can't find a possibility to deactivate the default node. How can I disable it?

**Startup log:**

```
[           main] org.elasticsearch.node                   : [Overkill] version[1.3.2], pid[2316], build[dee175d/2014-08-13T14:29:30Z]
[           main] org.elasticsearch.node                   : [Overkill] initializing ...
[           main] org.elasticsearch.plugins                : [Overkill] loaded [], sites []
[           main] org.elasticsearch.node                   : [Overkill] initialized
[           main] org.elasticsearch.node                   : [Overkill] starting ...
[           main] org.elasticsearch.transport              : [Overkill] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/192.168.173.22:9300]}
[           main] org.elasticsearch.discovery              : [Overkill] xyz/15kRC2sHR0SKamJerq0EXw
[           main] org.elasticsearch.discovery              : [Overkill] waited for 30s and no initial state was set by the discovery
[           main] org.elasticsearch.http                   : [Overkill] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/192.168.173.22:9200]}
[...]
[           main] org.elasticsearch.node                   : [Serpentina] version[1.3.2], pid[2316], build[dee175d/2014-08-13T14:29:30Z]
[           main] org.elasticsearch.node                   : [Serpentina] initializing ...
[           main] org.elasticsearch.plugins                : [Serpentina] loaded [], sites []
[           main] org.elasticsearch.node                   : [Serpentina] initialized
[           main] org.elasticsearch.node                   : [Serpentina] starting ...
[           main] org.elasticsearch.transport              : [Serpentina] bound_address {local[1]}, publish_address {local[1]}
[           main] org.elasticsearch.discovery              : [Serpentina] elasticsearch/f5g45CHHSaCqrD8AFyNGWQ
[pdateTask][T#1]] org.elasticsearch.cluster.service        : [Serpentina] new_master [Serpentina][f5g45CHHSaCqrD8AFyNGWQ][Blu][local[1]]{local=true}, reason: local-disco-initial_connect(master)
[           main] org.elasticsearch.node                   : [Serpentina] started
[pdateTask][T#1]] org.elasticsearch.gateway                : [Serpentina] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
```

**My ES class:**

```
@Repository
public class XyzRepository {

    private Node node;
    private Client client;

    public XyzRepository (){
        this.node = nodeBuilder().client(true).clusterName("clusterName").node();
        this.client = node.client();
    }

    [... some functions...]
}
```

**pom.xml**:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
[...properties...]
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    [...other dependencies...]
```

Comment: I think the correct property name is `spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.node.local`, can you try it?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Val. I tried `node.local=false`, `node.data=false` and `http.enabled=false` but none of them works. I still get two starting nodes.